# Power analysis for loglinear model

Tags: r, power-analysis

I have a loglinear model. How can I perform power analysis on it?
Using an example dataset:

```
library(MASS)
UCBAdf <- as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
```

My loglinear model:

```
glmFitT <- glm(Freq ~ Admit * Dept * Gender, family=poisson(link="log"), data=UCBAdf)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you over-fitting?

Comment: @Rui Barradas Yes, it is a saturated model. I just threw a model here to get some ideas how to run power analysis. -)